# Android instrumentation tests fail on Google's Test Lab Galaxy S9+ due to keyboard on-boarding popup

Tags: android, android-espresso, galaxy, firebase-test-lab

Occasionally, the instrumentation tests (Espresso) are failing on Google's Firebase Test Lab due to a keyboard on-boarding popup (screenshot) that blocks the screen and prevents tap/type events.

This only happens on the Samsung Galaxy S9+

[image]

Here is the exception:

> android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'type text(666666)' on view '(is descendant of a: (with id: XXX) and an instance of android.widget.EditText)'.
>
> Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.InjectEventSecurityException: java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
> at android.support.test.espresso.base.InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.injectKeyEvent(InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.java:113)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to play around with "ime" command from ADB to enable another keyboard (you can log for example the return of `ime list` in order to get the IDs) before running your tests (e.g. @Before):

```
getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand("ime enable ID");
Thread.sleep(1000);
getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand("ime set ID");
```

Else you can workaround with uiautomator and implement a check before using the keyboard with this kind of piece of code :

```
...
onView(withId(R.id.inputField)).perform(click());
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
    UiObject skipButton = device.findObject(new UiSelector().text("SKIP"));
    if (skipButton.exists()) {
        try {
            skipButton.click();
            Timber.e(e, "Dismissed popup on Keyboard");
        } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
            Timber.e(e, "There is no popup displayed on Keyboard");
        }
    }
}
onView(withId(R.id.inputField)).perform(typeText("some"), pressImeActionButton());
...
```

Hope this help !

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem. It's on Firebase Test Lab side, and you shouldn't try to find a workaround. Sometimes there are problems with devices you are not responsible for. Instead you should report about it to Firebase team directly if you want it to be fixed as soon as possible.

The fastest way to do it is to go to #test-lab channel of the [Firebase Slack community](https://firebase.community/) and report them about an issue like that. They will ask you to provide your matrix ID where you experienced something wrong.

As for layout popup, it was fixed the next day it was reported, so you shouldn't see it now.

Comment: I reported the issue, but we switched to using Pixel devices.